# Xp decomposition question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Solve $Ax = b$

Given

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}16&2&3&13\\5&11&10&8\\9&7&6&12\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$b = \begin{bmatrix}50\\39\\43\end{bmatrix}$$
I need to one : solve for $x_p$
and then 2=two: decompose $x_p = x_r +x_n$ where $x_r$ is within $C(A^T)$ (the column space of $A$ transpose) and $x_n$ is within $N(A)$ (the nullspace of $A$)

To solve for $x_p$,
I first augmented the matrix $A$ and $b$, then reduced the result to get

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&1&3\\0&1&0&3&4\\0&0&1&-3&-2\end{bmatrix}$$

So I have 3 pivot columns and 1 free column. Meaning, I would think I assign $0$ to the free column, and the reduced $b$ ($d$) as my pivot entries for

$$x_p = \begin{bmatrix}3\\4\\-2\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

I would first like to know if my intuition for the first part is correct, and then how to go about decomposing my $x_p$ into $x_n$ and $x_r$

Comment: MathJax is used to format mathematical expressions on this site. You can find a quick reference and tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @amd, you are correct, I have since edited. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To break down $x_{p} = x_{r} + x_{n}$, basically it will look like this:

$$ x_{1}\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
    16 \\
    2  \\
    3 \\
    13
\end{array}
\right] + x_{2}\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
    5 \\
    11  \\
    10 \\
    8
\end{array}
\right] + x_{3}\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
    9 \\
    7  \\
    6 \\
    12
\end{array}
\right] + x_{4}\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
    -1 \\
    -3  \\
    3 \\
    1
\end{array}
\right] =\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
    3 \\
    4  \\
    -2 \\
    0
\end{array}
\right]$$

Combine these into an augmented matrix:
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  16&5&9&-1&3\\
  2&11&7&-3&4\\
  3&10&6&3&-2\\
  13&8&12&1&0\\
\end{array}
\right] $$

Final result will be:
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  1&0&0&0&\frac{19}{85}\\
  0&1&0&0&\frac{319}{1360}\\
  0&0&1&0&\frac{-423}{1360}\\
  0&0&0&1&\frac{-21}{20}\\
\end{array}
\right] $$

So $x_{n}$ = 
$$ \frac{-21}{20}*\left[
\begin{array}{c}
-1\\
-3\\
3\\
1\\
\end{array}
\right] =
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{21}{20}\\
\frac{63}{20}\\
-\frac{63}{20}\\
-\frac{21}{20}\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

$x_{r}$ will be the same approach using $x_{1}, x_{2}$, and $x_{3}$ on the row space columns.